# Javascript arguments inside a .filter method

Tags: javascript, loops, arguments

I'm working on a problem, where I am provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. I need to remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

The function only takes 1 argument (the array), and there can be any number of additional arguments, which I can select as "arguments[index]".

Here is my code up to now:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    newArr= [ ];
    newArr = arr.filter(function(x){
        return x !== arguments[2]; //argumets[2] is equal to 3
    });
    return newArr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
// => returns [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
```

BUT if i enter 3, instead of arguments[2], the function returns [1,2,1,2].
What is going on?

Additionally, how can I loop through the code to test all other arguments, if I can't have a function in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

arguments refers to the arguments of the second function
you can do something like this

```
        function destroyer(arr) {
    newArr= [ ];
var args = arguments;
    newArr = arr.filter(function(x){
        return x !== args[2];
    });
    return newArr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a reference to the top `destroyer` argument. Then use *that* inside your `filter` function.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  newArr= [ ]; var args = arguments;
  newArr = arr.filter(function(x){
      return x !== args[2]; //destoryer's arguments[2] is equal to 3
  });
  return newArr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I check not just for args[2], but for args[arr.length-1] other arguments besides 0? I can create a loop inside a filter function, but it will cancel when I use first return...

Comment: Simply don't return until you've done everything you need to. I'm not clear on what you need to do with the loop, so I don't know how to help you more on that. Want to give us more of an idea of what you need to do?

Comment: I need to remove (filter) the elements in my argument[0] (the array), with all other arguments, which i can have as many as i want -arguments[positive whole numbers].
now since .filter removes an element from the array if the "return boolean" is false, i don't know how to loop through all elements, since loop will cancel with it sees "return".

Comment: So are you saying an array item has to match all arguments? None of the arguments? At least 1 argument?

Comment: Show me how the loop would look, put in the problematic returns and everything, and I'll have a better idea of what you're needing.